# Windows command line find and replace between brackets (repl.bat)

Tags: windows, batch-file, replace, cmd

I have a variable DATE, which contains something like 06092017
I have a file with the following line:

```
#define BUILDDATE (05092017)
```

where the value between the brackets changes

I'm trying to use this to find and replace the text:

```
type "file.h"|repl "(#define BUILDDATE \().*?(\))" "$1%DATE%$2" >"file_new.h"
```

But nothing has changed in `file_new.h`.
What am I doing wrong please? Or is there a better way?

Comment: It works for me. Are you sure "file.h" is ASCII, not Unicode? Note that I no longer support REPL.BAT. You should be using its successor [JREPL.BAT](http://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?t=6044) instead. And I have good news - I will be releasing a new version of JREPL.BAT in a matter of days that supports Unicode input and output.

Comment: `type` will convert from Unicode when piped

Comment: @Anders - Ugh, of course. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks guys. Just noticed that in my file.h, there was a tab between BUILDDATE and the brackets rather than a space that was causing it to fail. @dbenham Awesome, I'll update to JREPL.BAT

Comment: The simple solution would be to manually replace the line `#define BUILDDATE (05092017)` in `file.h` with `#include "builddate.h"` and then have your batch script do `echo #define BUILDDATE %DATE% > builddate.h`.

Comment: Thanks @Ross Ridge, yes that would work

Answer (score 0):

Why use a external script at all?

```
@echo off

REM Prepare example to make batch file self-contained (this will overwrite file.h!)
echo.#define whatever              > file.h
echo.#define BUILDDATE (05092017) >> file.h
echo.#define something (1234)     >> file.h

for /F "usebackq tokens=1,2,*" %%A in (`type "file.h"`) do @if "%%~A"=="#define" if "%%~B"=="BUILDDATE" (
    for /F "tokens=1 delims=() " %%X in ("%%~C") do (
        echo.%%X > "file_new.h"
    )
)

echo Result:
type "file_new.h"
```

Comment: Why not use a single FOR /F with `"delims=() tokens=1,2*"`, and check `if "%%A"=="#define BUILDDATE "` ?

Comment: @dbenham Unknown number of spaces and tabs between #define and BUILDDATE. I could still just use a single if with `"%%~A%%~B"=="#defineBUILDDATE"` I guess...

Answer (score 0):

Thanks guys. Just noticed that in my file.h, there was a tab between BUILDDATE and the brackets rather than a space that was causing it to fail.